# How is chlorophyll made in plants?

Tags: biochemistry

I've been studying photosynthesis and something made me think about how chlorophyll itself is made in plants.How exactly is it formed ?

Comment: This might be of interest: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorophyll#Biosynthesis

Answer (score 5):

[image]

In the first phase of chlorophyll biosynthesis, the amino acid **glutamic acid** is converted to **5-aminolevulinic acid** **(ALA)** . This reaction is unusual in that it involves a covalent intermediate in which the **glutamic acid** is attached to a transfer **RNA** molecule. This is one of a very small number of examples in biochemistry in which a **tRNA** is utilized in a process other than protein synthesis. Two molecules of **ALA** are then condensed to form **porphobilinogen (PBG)**, which ultimately form the **pyrrole** rings in chlorophyll. The next phase is the assembly of a **porphyrin** structure from four molecules of **PBG**. This phase consists of six distinct enzymatic steps, ending with the product **protoporphyrin IX**.

All the biosynthesis steps up to this point are the same for the synthesis of both **chlorophyll** and **heme**. But here the pathway branches, and the fate of the molecule depends on which metal is inserted into the center of the **porphyrin**. If **magnesium** is inserted by an enzyme called **magnesium chelatase**, then the additional steps needed to convert the molecule into **chlorophyll** take place; if **iron** is inserted, the species ultimately becomes heme.

The next phase of the chlorophyll biosynthetic pathway is the formation of the fifth ring (ring E) by cyclization of one of the **propionic acid** side chains to form **protochlorophyllide**. The pathway involves the reduction of one of the double bonds in ring D, using **NADPH**. This process is driven by light in angiosperms and is carried out by an enzyme called protochlorophyllide **oxidoreductase (POR)**. Non-oxygen-evolving photosynthetic bacteria carry out this reaction without light, using a completely different set of enzymes. **Cyanobacteria**, **algae**, lower plants, and **gymnosperms** contain both the light-dependent **POR** pathway and the light-independent pathway. Seedlings of **angiosperms** grown in complete darkness lack **chlorophyll**, because the **POR** enzyme requires light. These **etiolated** plants very rapidly turn green when exposed to light. The final step in the **chlorophyll** biosynthetic pathway is the attachment of the phytol tail, which is catalyzed by an enzyme called **chlorophyll synthetase** (*Malkin* and *Nyogi* **2000**).

---

<sub>Source: **[Plant Physiology Online: Chlorophyll Biosynthesis](http://5e.plantphys.net/article.php?ch=0&id=76)**</sub>